# Почему пакеты часто ставятся в основной Python, а не в виртуальное окружение?

Tags: python, pip

Делаю под каждый проект, где собираюсь использовать стороннюю библиотеку, отдельное виртуальное окружение.

Потом ставлю туда нужные пакеты, через pip install

Два пакета встало, я начал писать код, через некоторое время мне понадобился еще один, пытаюсь установить - а оно ставится в основной питон.
И это уже не в первый раз...
В командной строке конечно та папка, которая мне и нужна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На показанном вами скриншоте виртуальное окружение совершенно очевидно не включено, соответственно установка пойдёт в основной питон

Comment: andreymal, В смысле?
Я его активировал, установил beatifulSoup и requests, спарсил что нужно.
Теперь хочу импортировать в csv. Пытаюсь поставить нужный пакет, а он ставится в основной, а не в виртуальное.

Comment: И тем не менее на показанном вами скриншоте оно совершенно очевидно не активировано

Comment: Все спасибо. Я не знал, что нужно при каждом новом заходе в консоль снова активировать.

Answer (score 1):

Как определить в каком окружении вы находитесь.

1. В `cmd` должна быть указана папка в скобках для виртуального пространства. Она появляется после активации.

Изначально

```
C:\Users\Dmitry\proj>
```

В данной папке у меня лежит `venv`-папка с виртуальным пространством, т.е. если я вызову `dir`, то увижу следующее

```
C:\Users\Dmitry\proj>dir
 Directory of C:\Users\Dmitry\proj

17.02.2022  18:22    <DIR>          .
17.02.2022  18:22    <DIR>          ..
06.12.2021  08:33    <DIR>          venv
```

2. Теперь активирую виртуальное пространство и сразу в `cmd` можно увидеть, что я его использую (на вашем скрине, понятно, что вы не находитесь в виртуальном пространстве)

```
C:\Users\Dmitry\proj>venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) C:\Users\Dmitry\proj>
```

3. Из интерпретатора `python` можно спросить: какой `python` вы сейчас используете

```
(venv) C:\Users\Dmitry\proj>py
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python39\\lib', 
'C:\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\Dmitry\\proj\\venv', 
'C:\\Users\\Dmitry\\\proj\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Два послдених члена указывают на мою папку с виртуальным окружением

4. Если деактивировать пространство, то тогда вывод будет таким

```
C:\Users\Dmitry\proj>py
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python39\\lib', 
'C:\\Python39', 'C:\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
```

В этом случае, у меня глобальное окружение